# How can I set PyCharm to display the size of the variable in the variable window in debug mode?

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I set `PyCharm` to display the `size` of the variable in the variable window in `debug mode`, as follows:

```
df={Dataframe}(100,5)... View as Dataframe
```

My current `debug mode` `does not` display the size, as follows:

```
df={Dataframe}...View as Dataframe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click gear icon select -> Variables Loading Policy -> Asynchronously